# How to compile and run different languages in python in sand-boxed environment?

Tags: python, sandbox

Generally one can call other commands from python script using subprocess module or os.popen.

I'm working on the project (kind of programming judge) in which I need to compile and run different languages. (C,C++ and Python in first phase)

Is there any standard method to compile and run different languages from python script and also taking care of security of the system like avoiding system calls/fork bombs in these respective languages OR running these codes in sand-boxed environment?

Sandboxing python script is easy but how can I also control other languages like C and C++ while calling them from python script?

Comment: [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)?